# different scripts in html in development and production

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am using the concat grunt task:

```
concat: {
    dist: {
        src: [
            '../assets/js/jquery.js',
            '../assets/js/underscore.js',
            '../assets/js/pusher.js',
            '../assets/js/angular.js',
            '../assets/js/angular-resource.js',
            '../assets/js/angular-sanitize.js',

            '../core/module.js',
            '../core/**/*.js',

            'src/js/**/*.js'
        ],
        dest: 'dist/embed.js'
    }
},
```

Eventually I get one script file that contains all the scripts in dist/embed.js.
I also have an html file in src/index.html.
I am looking for a way to inject all those script file when running development tasks and inject only dist/embed.js on production task. I am trying nor to write again all the scripts in the index.html, but I want to use the list of scripts from the concat task.
Does anyone have idea how to handle this?
I'll appreciate examples very much.

Comment: Just use a condition -> `if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development')`

Comment: I'm not aware of how to exactly achieve this, but you should check out  [`grunt-env`](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-env), which allows you to define environment variables for future tasks in the chain.

Comment: @adeneo: But this way I would have to add all my dev scripts tags manually also to index.html!

Answer (score 0):

What I do in [unbox](https://github.com/bevacqua/unbox) is loop through a context variable in [my view layout](https://github.com/bevacqua/unbox/blob/master/src/client/views/layout.jade), loading all the necessary CSS and JS.

Those are passed to the Grunt task which compiles Jade views statically, so you could share the configuration to generate both `../assets/js/jquery.js` and `/js/jquery.js` style strings for each case.

Another option would be using [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin), although I only used it to update revved files, I know it can be used to transform these tags too. If you do want use usemin with Jade files, [usemin-patterns](https://github.com/bevacqua/usemin-patterns) might come in handy.

Comment: The problem with usemin is that I have to mention each and each script inside all my scripts folders. Where in concat task I can mention scripts directory and ask to load all of it. Do you have any idea how to do that?